# Confusion over length being used with NSArray in obj-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsobject

I'm using this line of code to go through an array

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[GameP objectForKey:@"groundMap"] length]; i += 5) {
```

Coming from an AS3 background, I presumed "length" would give me the length of an array/object, but I've just discovered "count" which seems to do the same thing, and I can't find any info on using "length" but it seems to work.

Can someone tell me..

1. What is "length" and how/why is it working in that line?
2. What's the difference between count and length?
3. Which is better to use?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Could you clarify what is returned by `[GameP objectForKey:@"groundMap"]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `GameP` is a dictionary, the call to `objectForKey:` returns an object of type `id`. So you are trying to call the `length` method on an `id`. This will compile fine but at runtime it is probably wrong assuming the object for "groundMap" is an array. An array only has a `count` method, no `length` method.

You are also accessing an object from the dictionary for every loop iteration. You really should write your code like this:

```
NSArray *groundMap = [GameP objectForKey:@"groundMap"];
NSUInteger count = groundMap.count;
for (int i = 0; i < count ; i += 5) {
}
```

This is easier to read and the compiler can do better error checking. It is also much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to know the class of the object at your dictionary `GameP`.
If that `NSArray` you have to use `count` here is no way to use another method.

You can find `length` method at `NSSString` class.